# Zookeeper for external Spring Boot application configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

I need a centralized configuration, High Availability tool. I did some research and think that Zookeeper will do the job. I am leveraging spring-cloud-zookeeper since my applications are Spring Boot apps.

These apps have application.yaml/.properties files & I want Zookeeper to make these configs available to the apps when they 1t start. I then want the ability to make changes to these configs at run-time & have the apps pick up the changes.

I have not seen a single example about how to have the Zookeeper server read these .yaml/.properties files in BEFORE the apps start? I've seen an example where there is a separate script (.sh) that runs & leverages zkCli.sh to insert values but that is pointless.

Comment: Zookeeper didn't designed to read these kind of config files. But if you want to store values of properties to zookeeper then you have to do it by your own script or your program.

Comment: Take a look at this article : https://www.stackextend.com/zookeeper/centralized-configuration-with-apache-zookeeper/

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @maspen, Zookeeper was designed for another use case.

One more option is to store configuration files in git repository like Github for example, then Spring Boot is able to read them and apply in runtime.

For more details check this out [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html).